# View data from database using textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have made some format in my access database,but when i try to view in textbox it not view the value using the format that i have set it. I use vb.net as a programming language and ms access as a database

Access database :

Field Name : sampleID
Data Type : AutoNumber
Format : "000000"

VB.net code :

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Cleaning"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)
    cnnOLEDB.Open()

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()

        txtSampleID.Text = dr("sampleID").ToString()

    End While
    dr.Close()
```

output in textbox after run program= 14

the actual output that i want to view is 000014

Comment: Do not add formatting to tables, it is rarely a good idea as it will lead to confusion about data types.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value being returned from sql is an integer, not a string.  You can change your code to re-format it the way you want:

```
    txtSampleID.Text = Cint(dr("sampleID")).ToString("00000#")
```

Comment: @user692495 It seems that this answer has solved your problem, if this is the case, you can accept the answer. The details are in the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Cleaning"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)
cnnOLEDB.Open()

Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read()

   txtSampleID.Text = Cint(dr("sampleID")).ToString("00000#")
End While
dr.Close()
```