# How to loop through MS Access table-column values pulled in a Combo box (VB .Net)

Tags: vb.net, combobox

This is in continuation of a previously resolved query related to Access Database values in Combo box. 
The code below is working fine. i.e. it gets the data from an Access table column into the dropdown of a combo-box. What I want is how to assign those values against the Combobox.SelectedIndex? I added  `TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0` but I want something that will automatically assign Index to the values populated in the combo-box dropdown.
The source table is tag_data '
Key Column  is tag_unique_id

I need it as I want to use the combobox.selectedindexchanged event to carry out further tasks. I played around but did not succeed.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim query As String = "select tag_unique_id from tag_data order by tag_unique_id"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
    Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
            connection.Open()
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    TagComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    TagComboBox1.ValueMember = "tag_unique_id"
    TagComboBox1.DisplayMember = "tag_unique_id"
    TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End If
```

**UPDATE:** Below is the combobox.selectedindexchanged code. The index can be anything during working of project and hence instead of specifying as `selectedindex=0 (1,2,3..)` can I have a variable which will assign a new value to selectedindexchanged event?

```
 Private Sub TagComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As system.EventArgs) Handles TagComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
'reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152534/view-data-from-database-using-textbox
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim query As String = "select tag_text from tag_data"
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
connection.Open()
If TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

    dr = command.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        TagTextBox.Text = dr("tag_text").ToString
    End While
    dr.Close()

End If
```

Comment: Are you talking about making a loop to do so?

Comment: yes..what I want is for each unique value in column tag_unique_id of tag_data table, an Index to be assigned when these values get populated in Combobox. Hence I want to loop though the values of in tag_unique_id and when each value is populated in combobox, I want it to be equal to  combobox.selectedindex . I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: Well if you are putting these values into a combobox, they will automatically be assigned a index value. the value is just the index of where they are in the combobox.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that tip. Now I have below statement which gets the data based on selected index from the table and puts it in a Textbox. I dont want add the code for each new combobox.selectedindex. Could you suggest what I can do? I have added the code in main post under UPDATE section.

[code]

Comment: just added in the main post Chase..thanks. based on the new selectedindex I want to get the tag_text in a textbox..its working for only current index(0) in above code.

Comment: what I observed now is when in the Main Application I add new tag (tag_unique_id ) and a description (tag_text) the code in my utulity picks up the text related to the latest tag_unique_id. When I change combo_box index it does not update the text related to other indexes.

Comment: You are adding another tag, then when you change the combobox, the label isn't updated?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to populate a textbox according to the selected index of the combobox this is what you need to do.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To (ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        textbox.Text = ComboBox1.Items(index)
    Next
```

Comment: got error as length is not a member of 'system.windows.forms.Combobox' for combobox.length()

and 

Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection' cannot be converted to 'String' for combobox.Items[index]

Comment: I apologize, vb.net is not my native language. I have updated, and tested it. It works

Comment: Thanks.. got error during debugging.. "Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid." do I have to also enable the "If TagComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then ,... " as I had commented it out. can u pls show me where your code would fit in my above code? may be I am doing something wrong here..

Comment: I don't think you will need that. Try putting `.ToString()` to convert it from DataRowView to String.